# Apply or inherit view settings of parent object

Tags: parent

What is the easiest way to apply the view settings of an object to all of its (grand/grand/etc)children?
I used to put the parent + children into one collection and changing the collection's view did the trick, but I was wondering if there is a setting which lets me also inherit the view settings and not only transformation settings from a parent to its (grand)children.

If this pops up in the search, I am very sorry that I did not find it. Searching for "apply parent view" etc. gives a quite general search result without any specific questions. Any links to relevant questions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding Shift while clicking the view icons in the outliner does exactly what I was looking for.
Sometimes you can look for so long, and right after you ask for help you find the answer immediately :D